# Can we remove the null character at the end of CString?

Tags: mfc, c-strings

Can we remove the Null Character from the `CString`.  I am trying to copy a `unsigned char` and convert it to `CString`. But additionally a null character gets added. Is their way to remove it ???

Comment: Why is the null character an issue? Please show some context in the form of code. The real problem you are having is propably somewhere else, in the code we can't see.

Comment: This is a real [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 1):

The terminating NUL character technically isn't part of the `CString`. It gets stored to enable passing a `CString` to a function expecting a C-style string. There is no way to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make any sense. `CString` (and `std::string`) are there as implementations of C-style null terminated strings. They were designed to ALWAYS have the terminating null.

If you want to use something else, try:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<unsigned char> vectUnsignedChars;
```

With such a structure you can append data and it won't append a null.  But, if you try and pass it to a function that expects null terminated strings, expect a disaster.

Comment: Neither `CString` nor `std::string` are implementations of C-style strings. Quite to the contrary, as either one can contain embedded NUL characters. The terminating NUL character is technically not part of the controlled sequence in either class. It's there purely to allow passing the string to interfaces expecting C-style strings with zero overhead. It's decidedly not part of the string.